# How to run an RSpec test after a specified length of time?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rspec, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am working on RSpec smoke tests. The project that I need to test makes asynchronous calls, so I need to do some test cases after a specified length of time.

Example:

```
describe "Whatever Test Automation" do
  context "When logged in .." do
    it "does specific things" do
      bla bla ..
    end

    it "does specific things 2" do
      bla bla ..
    end

  end
end
```

How can I run the second test after a specified length of time, let`s say 20 minutes? If it is not possible to do that in code, Is there any configuration in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to be sure that test order is exactly the same all the time. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/command-line/order

You could set sleep in around block https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/hooks/around-hooks

Spec run that takes longer than 20 minutes is a bad smell. I would check for options to mock long process during test. Another good direction could be `rspec-wait` gem to wait for assertion as long as you need.

P.S. In Jenkins you could call one test per time with command like `rspec /spec/controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:42`, combining one test per run you could build any weird combinations with sleep between runs.

Answer (score 3):

Two points: this is really one test, and you need to find a way to reduce the time it takes to run.

Regarding test structure, **your second test isn't really an independent test**. It depends on the first test having run. The two should be written as a single test. In RSpec, smoke tests are probably best written as [feature specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) (not because of the Capybara integration, but because the `feature` and `scenario` syntax is conceptually right for acceptance tests). It's appropriate to have more than one group of expectations in a single scenario. So, as a first pass, I'd write this:

```
feature "Smoke tests" do
  context "Logged in" do
    scenario "User starts a long-running process" do
      # Do whatever starts the process
      # Expect the initial (immediate) results of the process
      sleep 20 * 60
      # Expect the asynchronous results of the process
    end
  end
end
```

Regarding test runtime, it would be terrible to have to run a 20-minute single test every time you smoke-tested a version of your software. **Anything you can do to reduce that 20 minutes will be a huge benefit to your company.** I don't know why it takes 20 minutes to test the process you're testing, but here are three considerations:

- If there is actually 20 minutes of work (computation) to do, give the smoke test less work. For example, if the time to complete the process depends on the size of the input data, give it a minimal set of data to work on.
- If part of that 20 minutes is just an arbitrary delay, provide a way for a privileged user to control the delay and use that mechanism in your smoke test to set the delay to as small a value as possible while still being valid as a smoke test. Add that mechanism to production code (rather than doing something test-specific like a stub) so that the smoke test is still testing production code.
- If part of that 20 minutes is simply waiting long enough to be sure that the process has completed, minimize that by polling. The rspec-wait gem that uzzer suggested is a good example of that tactic. You could write your own polling if rspec-wait's waiting algorithm (it just checks every `wait_delay` until it reaches a `wait_timeout`) doesn't work well for you.